# facescontext.getcurrentinstance returns nullpointerexception

Tags: java, spring, jsf

I am creating a Spring based JSF application, where I am getting FacesContext.getCurrentInstance which returns null.

Here is my Java code

```
public static ServletContext getServletContext() 
{       
    return (ServletContext) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance()
    .getExternalContext().getContext();
}
```

This is the stack trace of my error

```
SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class    
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dbSettingsServiceTarget' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [com.smartcall.service.impl.DbSettingsServiceImpl]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:883)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:839)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:440)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory$1.run(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:409)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:380)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:264)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:221)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:261)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:185)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:164)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:429)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:729)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:381)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.createWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:255)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:199)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:45)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:3972)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4467)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1045)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.start(StandardHost.java:785)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1045)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.start(StandardEngine.java:443)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.start(StandardService.java:519)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.start(StandardServer.java:710)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:581)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:289)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:414)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate     bean class [com.smartcall.service.impl.DbSettingsServiceImpl]:    Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:115)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:61)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:877)
... 31 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.smartcall.util.FacesUtil.getServletContext(FacesUtil.java:21)
at com.smartcall.util.SpringApplicationContextUtil.init(SpringApplicationContextUtil.java:21)
at com.smartcall.util.SpringApplicationContextUtil.<init>(SpringApplicationContextUtil.java:16)
at com.smartcall.service.impl.DbSettingsServiceImpl.init(DbSettingsServiceImpl.java:17)
at com.smartcall.service.impl.DbSettingsServiceImpl.<init>(DbSettingsServiceImpl.java:12)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:100)
... 33 more
```

and hence due to this error Server console in Eclipse reports that application failed to startup due to previous errors

My web.xml file

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"  xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
  <display-name>smartcall2.0</display-name>
  <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.faces.STATE_SAVING_METHOD</param-name>
    <param-value>server</param-value>
</context-param>

<context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.CONFIG_FILES</param-name>
    <param-value>
        /WEB-INF/faces-config.xml,/WEB-INF/faces-managed-bean.xml,/WEB-INF/faces-navigation.xml
    </param-value>
</context-param>

<listener>
    <listener-class>
        com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener
    </listener-class>
</listener>

<listener>
    <listener-class>
        org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
    </listener-class>
</listener>

<filter>
    <display-name>RichFaces Filter</display-name>
    <filter-name>richfaces</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.ajax4jsf.Filter</filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>richfaces</filter-name>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
    <dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher>
    <dispatcher>INCLUDE</dispatcher>
</filter-mapping>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<context-param>
  <param-name>javax.faces.DEFAULT_SUFFIX</param-name>
  <param-value>.xhtml</param-value>
 </context-param>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.jsf</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<session-config>
   <session-timeout>180</session-timeout>
</session-config>

<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
```

I am not clear whether this error belongs to Spring or JSF or Eclipse.

I am using Eclipse Galileo, JSF 1.2,Spring 3

Please help
Thanks in advance

**UPDATE**

```
<!-- dbSettings Service Definition -->
<bean id="dbSettingsServiceTarget"
    class="com.smartcall.service.impl.DbSettingsServiceImpl">
    <property name="dbSettingsDAO">
        <ref local="dbSettingsDAO" />
    </property> 
</bean>
```

these lines in application-context.xml causes the problem.

**UPDATE**

This is the code of DbSettingsServiceImpl.

```
public class DbSettingsServiceImpl implements DbSettingsService
{
private SpringApplicationContextUtil springApplicationContextUtil = null;

private DbSettingsDAO dbSettingsDAO;

public DbSettingsServiceImpl()
{
    init();
}

public void init()
{
    springApplicationContextUtil = new SpringApplicationContextUtil();      
}



public DbSettingsDAO getDbSettingsDAO() {
    return dbSettingsDAO;
}

public void setDbSettingsDAO(DbSettingsDAO dbSettingsDAO) {
    this.dbSettingsDAO = dbSettingsDAO;
}

public String getDatabaseNameFromSettings() 
{

    return springApplicationContextUtil.getDatabaseDetailForThePropery("username");
}

public String getDatabasePasswordFromSettings() 
{   
    return springApplicationContextUtil.getDatabaseDetailForThePropery("password");
}

public String getDatabaseServerNameFromSettings() 
{   
    return springApplicationContextUtil.getDatabaseDetailForThePropery("server");
}

public String getDatabaseUserNameFromSettings() 
{

    return springApplicationContextUtil.getDatabaseDetailForThePropery("username");
}
}
```

**Update**

This piece of code in SpringApplicationContextUtil code causing the problem

```
ServletContext servletContext = FacesUtil.getServletContext();
    this.context = WebApplicationContextUtils
            .getRequiredWebApplicationContext(servletContext);
```

When I moved this code from constructor to the method the problem solved.  Can any one predict why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess would be your problem is in your spring configuration:  All the errors are thrown by the spring framework, the error code says you have a problem with the ContextInitialized event, and you have assigned a ContextLoadedListener in your web.xml.  I would start looking for the cause there.

Comment: Thank you for looking at my problem.  Actually this worked fine yesterday.  But I don't know why it failed today.

Comment: Well, have you changed anything since then?

Comment: That's the problem.  I don't remember exactly what change caused the problem.  Is there any way in Eclipse to revert back to the previous day code?

Comment: You can use CVS, SVN and such directly from eclipse, but you have to set up versioning BEFORE you need it.  Try commenting out some of the features you have added since yesterday.  Maybe that will help track down the problem.

Comment: @weltraumpirat +1 you are correct the lines I posted above caused the problem.  Can you spot out why? please check my update

Comment: Since instantiating your DBSettingsServiceImpl throws a NullPointerException (check the stack trace), I believe the problem is not in the lines you posted, but that there is either something wrong with the DBSettingsServiceImpl constructor, or you have no local declaration of dbSettingsDAO in the same application-context.xml file.

Comment: @weltraumpirat plz check my update.  Can you spot out any problems?

Comment: Can't say for sure without the rest of the code, but since it's the constructor causing the exception - is it possible you are instantiating a static class with "new"? SpringApplicationContextUtil sounds like one.

Comment: SpringApplicationContextUtil is not static

Comment: I just looked at the stack trace again and saw the NullPointerException seems to be thrown here: com.smartcall.util.FacesUtil.getServletContext(FacesUtil.java:21)  Looks like the context isn't initialized correctly.

Comment: Ah!! This is the first java code I posted above.  Is it useful?

Comment: I found the problem, it was the SpringApplicationContextUtil constructor causing the problem.  Plz check my update!!!

Comment: It seems like the bean is initialized sooner the ServletContext.  So trying to get an instance in the constructor of the bean will obviously return null.